# Evaluation of a class of continued fractions

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-equations, closed-form, continued-fractions

Is there a closed-form way of writing the continued fraction:
$$
1 + \frac{2}{3+ \frac{4}{5 + \frac{6}{7 + ...}}}
$$
**EDIT:** Since the above has been determined as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}-1}$, is there a similar expression for:
$$
2 + \frac{3}{4+ \frac{5}{6 + \frac{7}{8 + ...}}}
$$
More generally, are there general closed-form expressions for all continued fractions of the form:
$$
a_n = n + \frac{n+1}{(n+2) + \frac{n+3}{(n+4) + ...}} \\
f(x) = x + \frac{x+1}{(x+2) + \frac{x+3}{(x+4) + \cdots}} = x + \frac{x+1}{f(x+2)} \\
f(x) f(x+2) = xf(x+2) + x+1
$$
And can said closed form be extended to all real numbers? For example, I experimented with extending the sequence to negative values of n and found that for all negative odd $n, a_n = -1$.

Comment: You can find your continued fraction [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFraction.html).

Comment: A derivation can be found in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0508227v1.pdf) by Leonhard Euler. See page 14.

Comment: A more general formula can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction#Transcendental_functions_and_numbers).

Comment: Perhaps you find this http://go.helms-net.de/math/divers/GenContFracRationalE.htm interesting, although the sequences of coefficients in your CF goe in steps of 2 and I've a table of CF's with sequences going in steps of 1. But perhaps the table as such is of interest and gives an idea for the analoguous table for your version

Answer (score 1):

It's $1/(e^{1/2}-1)$.  You should be able to derive this by doing a term-by-term transformation on an appropriate infinite series.

Comment: Could you clarify how you did this? Also, how would you evaluate $a_0$ and more generally $a_n$?

Answer (score 1):

If $$z_1 = 1 + 2/(3 + 4/(5 + 6/( ... = {1\over \exp(1/2)-1 }$$ (as given in the answer before) and $$z_3 =3 + 4/(5 + 6/( ... $$ then $$ z_1 = 1 + 2/z_3$$ or $$z_3 = { 2 \over z_1-1} = { 2 \over {1 \over \exp(1/2)-1}-1} =   { 2 \exp(1/2)-2 \over 2 - \exp(1/2) }  $$
From this $z_5,z_7,...$ follow analoguously, and they are ***all rational compositions*** of the "magic" constant $\beta= \frac 1{\sqrt{ e}}$ in the form $$ { 1\over z_{2k+1} +1} = a_{2k+1} + b_{2k+1} \beta $$.

For the even indexed $z_{2k}$ the rule is the same, however I did not yet find their "magic constant", say $\gamma$ .

---

Just for the visualization, I made a table focusing on the cases, where the continued fraction becomes rational. The grey-shaded entries indicate evaluation of the cont-fractions to irrational numbers. The two yellow entried are the two known irrational numbers:
[image]